# Maven - installed to local repo, not getting transitive dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, transitive-dependency

I have a maven project that I'd like to share with several of my other projects.  It has some custom code, and then a few dependencies on things like log4j, jasypt, etc.

I build it and install it to my local maven repo.  I can see it's successfully put there.  Looking at .m2/repository/derp/Foo/1.0 it has a .pom with all its dependencies defined.

I can also define it as a dependency in my higher level projects, and it compiles.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can see the Jar in my 'Maven Dependencies' in eclipse, and expanding that jar I can see it has the correct pom with dependencies in META-INF/maven/derp/Foo/pom.xml.

But my top level project above Foo isn't getting the dependencies that Foo needs.  I get runtime exceptions, and I can see none of the transitive dependency jars are in my maven dependencies in eclipse.

What do I need to do to make sure Maven knows to look at the Pom for Foo in my local repo, so it will get all the transitive dependencies it needs?

----- edit -----

Answer to comment below, they are defined like this, with the dependencies tag at the top level under the project tag.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

etc...

These are the jars that maven correctly finds when I am just building and running this Foo project, but maven doesn't include these jars if a project depends on Foo, (Bar), and I find out when I try to run Bar.

Comment: can you share how dependencies are defined in Foo pom? are they in a dependencyManagement? in dependencies section, in which scope are they?

Comment: Included edit in my post to answer your comment.  My solution for now is to make a 'shaded' Foo jar that includes all the jars that are not getting included in project above Foo.

Answer (score 1):

What does "top level project above Foo isn't getting the dependencies" mean?

Anything "above" `Foo` in the build reactor should depend directly on `Foo` as you have stated.  The `<dependency/>` specified will [resolve to](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) `Foo`'s dependencies (within the scope that `Foo` specifies).

Without understanding the specifics of your project, it's improbable that we can to help you any further.

Some possible common situations:

1. You expect to be able to get access to `test` scoped dependencies in some non-`test` phase of execution.  Just not true.
2. You expect that specifying a dependency on an artifact causes the *`java`* runtime to load those dependencies for you automagically.  That's also not true.  
   You'll want to invoke the `exec:java` goal on the [maven exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) and specify your desired resolution scope within the `<configuration/>`, possibly also for that `<execution/>`.
3. You've mistaken `<dependencyManagement>` for `<dependencies>`.  This happens way more than I would have expected.

Comment: I think #3 may be my problem.  Going to RTFM now...  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management